# Inverse Laplace with formula table

Tags: inverse-laplace

In my book I have to do the inverse Laplace transform of:
$$\displaystyle \frac{4 + 15 s}{s(2+5s)} = \frac{15}{5} \frac{\left(s + \frac{4}{15}\right)}{s\left(s + \frac{2}{5}\right)}$$

With a partial fraction division, I can find that one fraction is $\displaystyle\frac{2}{s}$ and the second $\displaystyle\frac{5}{5s+2}$ and I can find $e^{-\frac{2}{5}t} + 2$.

But the book states that I should get it directly by looking at the summary of usual Laplace transforms? I checked the formulas and did not find what I should be able to see.
Can someone help me to navigate the classical formula table given that equation?

Comment: The _inverse_ for $ \ \frac{2}{s} \ $ is not simply $ \ 2 \ $ .

Comment: It says $2$ in the book (time function). Would you care to expand?

Comment: Some tables give the inverse as $ \ 2 \ H(t) \ $ ; I'm taking it that if your answer wasn't acceptable, it might be because a "step function" at $ \ t  =  0 \ $ was intended.

Comment: My answer is correct, discussing my answer is NOT what I am asking. When it comes to differential equations, with or without time function the inverse laplace transform of a constant a is a/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Esullivan/22files/New%20Laplace%20Transform%20Table.pdf). Formula  $14.$

Write $\frac{15 s+4}{s (5 s+2)}$
as $$\frac{15}{5} \frac{\left(s + \frac{4}{15}\right)}{s\left(s + \frac{2}{5}\right)}$$
$\alpha=\frac{4}{15};\;a=0;\;b=\frac{2}{5}$
$$3\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{2}{5}} \left[\frac{4}{15}e^0-\left(\frac{4}{15}-\frac{2}{5}\right)e^{-2/5t}\right]=\frac{15}{2}\left(\frac{4}{15}+\frac{2}{15}e^{-2/5t}\right)=2+e^{-2/5t}$$

Tbh I prefer your solution :)

Comment: awwwww thanks !